# Encrypting a Python Wheel

Tags: python, encryption, python-wheel

I am looking for ways to encrypt an in-house python package, preferably a .whl.

I do not need the source code itself to be obscured, only verification that the person trying to unpack the wheel is an authorized user who has the encryption key.

Does anyone have ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Probably not in the .whl file format but you can encrypt it like any other file.

Comment: If you just want symmetric encryption (i.e. there's one encryption key, either you know it or you don't), you should probably use AES.  If you need asymmetric encryption (Alice encrypts, Bob decrypts, and they *do not share a secret key*), I'd go for some implementation of OpenPGP, such as GnuPG.

Comment: I was hoping to throw my package up a secure url, and then colleagues who needed it (or needed an update) could just pip install from that url, which makes the process very plug-and-play.  Encryption would give extra piece of mind that not just anyone could get access, but unfortunately, encrypting the whole file adds extra steps.